# AzerothCore Unable to connect to server, probably WorldSocket Malformed request sent by client

Tags: c++, authentication, azerothcore

I am using AzerothCore locally and when I try to log in - I am stuck at "Authenticating".

Previously on login attempt - a error occured, WorldSocket Malformed request sent by client, But after opening the ports for both inbound and outbound connections - it dissapeared.

Therefore, no error message, just stuck at "Authenticating".
Client version: 3.3.5 (13240) (Release)
Jan 24 2010

The realmList is changed to 127.0.0.1:8085 But I am not sure if it is correct, since once I had issues accessing localhost on another application and had to use the router's IP (192.168.0.3)

[image: AuthServer]

[image: WorldServer]

[image: RealmList]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> WorldSocket Malformed request sent by client

`WorldSocket::ReadHeaderHandler(): client 111.222.11.22 sent malformed packet (size: 1234, cmd: 3333333)`
means some machine anywhere on the planet sent a random portscan to your IP.
Not related to your actual problem.

You should try and set the realmlist to the LAN IP of the machine running the server and do the same in the `realmlist` table.
Also make sure all ports are properly forwarded to your server. (8085 und 3724 by default).

If both, client and server are running on the same machine, you can use 127.0.0.1. Not otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Solved:
On the client, use set realmlist 127.0.0.1
Without the port